# that you saw vs. what you saw

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Was what you saw in Scotland better than ***that/what*** you saw in France?

I think it should be ***what***. Am I right?

Comment: Correct.  To use "that", you would need something like the tortured: "...than that which you saw in France."

Comment: @fixer1234  So basically you can replace 'what' with 'that which' in this kind of structure?

Comment: Yes, in fact, that's one of the definitions of "what".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, *what* is correct.  It creates a parallel construction.

> Is *what* you saw in Scotland better than *what* you saw in France?

If you had more context, you might be able to get away with using *that*

> Is *what* you saw in Scotland better than *that*?

but the listener would have to know what *that* was.